# How get first filename and rename it to new file in Automator on macOS?

Tags: macos, pdf, merge, automator

I cannot find how can I do this with Automator on macOS:

We are merging 2 or more PDF files into (new) one. New file should be named as first original file.
So I need:

1. Take name of first original file - via script?
2. merge all original file - via Automator action "Combine PDF pages".
3. (Maybe?) Rename first (or all) original file(s) into suffix _old.pdf (is it needed? Because new and old file are/should be in the same folder).
4. Rename new merged PDF with name of first original file.

I tried many, many tries and at this moment I've done the best I can.

My latest try is:

[image]